# How can I configure multiple formatters to run in a sequence on save in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on a Haskell project that must be formatted by *both*:

- `stylish-haskell` (for import reordering)
- `brittany` (for general formatting)

I can set the single default formatter for a language:

```
"[haskell]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "MaxGabriel.brittany"
}
```

or I can select one from a list using `editor.action.formatDocument.multiple` ("Format Document With... in the command palette).

But I need to run both of them, one after the other, on save. As of right now, I can only run the single default formatter on save. The order doesn't matter in this case, but it could in more general cases.

I've tried setting `editor.defaultFormatter` to a list of formatters (this didn't work, as expected) and built a local extension that calls `editor.action.formatDocument.multiple` with various arguments, which just brings up a drop-down list of available formatters to choose from.

How can I run both formatters sequentially on save?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is really a use case that is officially supported, but you could possibly work around it by having an extension do the following:

- disable `"editor.formatOnSave"` for Haskell
- register a callback for [`vscode.workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument), in which you:

  - set `"editor.defaultFormatter"` to the first formatter using the [`WorkspaceConfiguration`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration) API
  - call `"editor.action.formatDocument"`
  - set `"editor.defaultFormatter"` to the second formatter
  - call `"editor.action.formatDocument"` again

Of course, this only covers `formatOnSave` formatting, not `formatOnPaste` or `formatOnType`.

Comment: Is it possible to run it via custom keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit late but, for newcomers, you can also use one extension that is already created... and it's thanks to all the answers of this post, by the way.

See [Multi Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Jota0222.multi-formatter)

So you can just add the formatters you want to run in the `settings.json` or the `*.code-workspace` settings like this:

```json
{
    "[haskell]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "Jota0222.multi-formatter",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
        "multiFormatter.formatterList": [
            "vigoo.stylish-haskell",
            "MaxGabriel.brittany"
        ],
    }
}
```

With that configuration, `stylish-haskell` will run first and `Britanny` will run just after once you save the changes.

**P.S.**: I'm indeed the author of the solution. I'm not aiming to do any promotion, it's just an implementation of the answers above. So I'll like to thank the people that answered before me.

Also, the extension is open sourced, feel free to check the code and contribute [on GitHub](https://github.com/jota0222/MultiFormatterVSCode)

Answer (score 0):

Last thoughts: look at [Run on Save extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) and execute your formatters not as extensions but as scripts.

Previous edit:

If your formatter doesn't contribute a command (see discussion in comments for some that do) as it appears `brittany` does not, try something like this for its task:

```
{
    "label": "brittany format step",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "brittany ${file}",
    "problemMatcher": []
}
```

---

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here... There's only one formatter command, which formats with the default formatter. How do you get it to switch to a different formatter purely using tasks?

Comment: I installed one of the OP's formatters  as a test: `stylish-haskell` and it contributed the command `stylishHaskell.runOnCurrent` which I assume you could call in a task or macro.  Looking at `brittany` it doesn't appear to do this - but perhaps it could be called in a script in a task.  Or if not, set 'brittany

Comment: set `brittany` to be the default and call `editor.action.formatDocument` after the `stylishHaskell.runOnCurrent` command.

Comment: I see the extension `hindent-format` has the command `hindent-format.format` so perhaps that could be used in a task or macro as well.

Comment: In general, it doesn't seem possible to call a specific formatter; that is one of the big blockers here.

Comment: I am wondering what the command `stylishHaskell.runOnCurrent` does?  It is in the command palette...

Answer (score 0):

From Gama11's answer of creating a VSCode extension:

The following code specifies the formatter and then formats the code.

```js
const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('editor', vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document);
await config.update('defaultFormatter', 'MaxGabriel.brittany');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.formatDocument');
```

Therefore, the answer is:

```js
const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('editor', vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document);
const formatters = ['MaxGabriel.brittany', 'ms-python.python'];
formatters.forEach(async formatter => {
    await config.update('defaultFormatter', formatter);
    await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.formatDocument');
});
```