# VSCode use different formatter conditionally

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatter

I'm using eslint and prettier plugins for vscode, both of them offer code formatting.
I prefer eslint formatting because it formats according to eslint rules so I made it my default formatter.

But some of my projects don't use eslint and when I'm trying to autoformat document it yells at me saying eslint is unavailable in here.

I know I can create `settings.json` file in `.vscode` folder but is there a way to conditionally use different formatter if the one in use is not available?

Like if eslint is unavailable, use prettier.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57616665/how-can-i-configure-multiple-formatters-to-run-in-a-sequence-on-save-in-vscode) solution can help you achieve what you want.

Comment: It might work. Thanks @lbarqueira