# onDidSaveTextDocument causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create an extension that runs two formatters in succession to format a file on save.

The idea comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57617310/8685682), so I assume it must be possible.

My extension's code looks like this:

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    vscode.workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument(() => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from mojo.formatter!');
        const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration(
          "editor",
          vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document
        );
        const formatters = ["esbenp.prettier-vscode", "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"];
        formatters.forEach(async (formatter) => {
          await config.update("defaultFormatter", formatter);
          await vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.formatDocument");
        });
    });

}
```

I've also added the following to my `package.json`:

```
  "activationEvents": [
    "*"
  ],
```

Everything else is the same as it comes in the Hello world extension example.

When I save a document, the formatters run but the extension seems to create an infinite loop of

- Saving
- Formatting
- Saving again
- Formatting

And so on...

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Does one of the formatters save the document when it's done formatting?

Comment: The command being used is just the default VScode format document, which doesn't save.

I think the issue is that the line which sets the default formatter is saving a `settings.json` file somewhere, which is causing the loop. I have no idea how to exclude it though.